# PHP (7.2.23) Update version not working when installing composer in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm installing a project from git. When I try to install composer it shows message that require PHP 7.2 your version 7.1.1

But my PHP version is 7.2.23, I have checked it locally from `http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php`.

Error message from PhpStorm editor:

> This package requires php ^7.2 but your PHP version (7.1.1) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Did you try a simple `>php -v` from a terminal to check your PHP CLI  version. Composer does use the CLI afterall

Comment: Yes, it shows php 7.2

Comment: Yes, it shows _php 7.2_ from terminal, but showing 7.1 from _php storm_ terminal where i was trying to install _composer_ and it gives error that need _php 7.2_ your _current version is 7.1_

Comment: If you've got multiple PHP versions installed, you can select the CLI version you want to use in PHPStorm's settings. If you don't need 7.1 anymore, just uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, Solved this problem, there was problem on php storm editor where latest php version were 7.1, its working from other terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try disable php 7.1

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or better uninstall php7.1

```
apt remove --purge php7.1 php7.1*
```